# How to use Blazor method from dynamically loaded SVG onclick attribute

Tags: svg, blazor, blazor-server-side

I load SVG at runtime to my razor component. Inside one of the SVG elements I have 'onclick' attribute.
How to catch the onclick event in Blazor code?

Example Razor component:

```
<PageTitle>@boardName</PageTitle>

<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1200 664">
    @SvgContent
</svg>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int boardId { get; set; }
    private string svgText;
    ...
    ...
    private RenderFragment SvgContent => (builder) =>
    {
        builder.AddMarkupContent(0, $"{svgText}");
    };
    private LoadSvg(string svg)
    {
        svgText = svg;
    }
    private void DoCoolStuff()
    {
        // cool stuff
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

At runtime I load svg string to variable svgText, example svg:

```
<svg>
<rect
   id="rect6563"
   width="203.47968"
   height="28.103336"
   x="57.955502"
   y="58.959087"
   onclick="DoCoolStuff()"
 />
</svg>
```

and when I click on the rectangle i would like to DoCoolStuff() which is implemented inside Razor component. How to do it?

When 'onclick' looks like: onclick="alert('You have clicked the rect.')", then the alert shows up, so the event is handled. But how to DoCoolStuff()?

Comment: What is the variation inside the svg?  Could there be 2 onclick events, or other events?

Comment: Yes, there may be more events. If the user will click on some elements, will be sent different messages over mqtt. I was able to do this using IJSRuntime and calling javascript commands (DotNetObjectReference.InvokeMethodAsync()). But can it be done without call javascript functions?

Comment: No, normally the `@onclick` is converted by the Razor compiler. But you bypass that so JavaScript is your only option here.

Comment: Any reason no to use `MarkupString SvgContent => (MarkupString)svgText;` here?

Comment: Sorry for late answert. I tried to use "MarkupString" before, but @onclick didn't work.
For example, I use this simple SVG:
<rect 
          width="203.47968"
          height="28.103336"
          x="57.955502"
          y="58.959087"
          @onclick='()=>OnSvgClick("rect1")'
 />
When the above svg is statically embedded, the OnSvgClick() function is called properly when clicked. But if I add this SVG as text at runtime using (MarkupString)svgText,  then the function is not called. Unless I'm doing it wrong? 
I solved this problem using JS, but it would be nice do it without JS.